# Cookie received in response but not getting saved

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm receiving a `Set-Cookie` header in response as shown in this image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OiHXRSW.png]

But it is not being set i.e. it is not visible in `Resource -> Cookies` in Chrome.   What can I do about it or is it a problem with the API?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you write a JavaScript which has access to the data? Have you tried running the cookie thru a verifier to ensure it is valid? Maybe try this URL? http://www.html-kit.com/tools/cookietester/

Comment: Are you running the test script through a site hosted at a valid domain name?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I think so..I uploaded the site to parse.com

Comment: @E.Maggini I tried to trace the problem using fiddler and got this under cookies  [link](http://i.imgur.com/KpoqlhL.png). Only cookie name and value are recieved. Is some extra info required like path or expiry etc?

Comment: Do you really work for parse.com?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No!!! I'meant was using parse.com for hosting my site.

Comment: But are you cookies binding to a `parse.com` subdomain or something? Do you mean that it works in local?